# Understanding menus and module pages in grav

Tags: grav

Maybe I missed something in the documentations of grav. I'm new to grav and it seems a very basic question to me: I'm using a fresh setup of grav, using the quark template. Why does the main menu (home, typography) disappear on module pages? How can I make it reappear to show the usual folder structure of `/root` instead of the modules?